# Swift 2.0 String of JSON to JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift2

I'm working in Swift 2.0 and struggling with JSON. I am pulling JSON from a website in the form of `Swift.Optional<NSData>`. I can convert it to a string using

```
if let x = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
  let y = x as String
}
```

I'm trying to get this JSON data into a dictionary in swift and struggling. What's the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    if let z = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {
    }
```

It errors with

- Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context
- Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, if a function "throws" (as `NSJSONSerialization` does), you have to handle the function call inside a `do ... catch` block and use `try` before the throwing function, like this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    do {
        let z = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [NSObject: AnyObject]
        print(z)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
}

task!.resume()
```

*Note that in this example, the possible `NSJSONSerialization` failure is handled by `do...catch` and `try` with a custom `myJSONError` error, but the possible failure of `NSURLSession` is not handled: you still have to check for the `error` variable in order to handle this. This is because `NSJSONSerialization` "throws" but `NSURLSession` does not.*

Comment: Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context [let z = ...]

Comment: Look at my [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/9dc6fc69-b44a-41bd-b20e-3cd044a22d76/5ff64f7c8c02a4b0/res/79e633de-c80b-416d-b3b3-b8a058425ce8/skitch.png), there's no error for my example. The error you get is not related to the JSON decoding. Try changing the name of the variables to get the compiler happy, he doesn't like your `z`. :) You probably get this because of some other variable or function in your code, elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to a string. You can do this:

```
if let JSONDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [NSObject: AnyObject] 
{
    // Do stuff with the JSONDict which is a Swift dictionary.
    // For example: let some = JSONDict["key"] as? ValueType will allow you to access the key of the JSONDict
}
```

If you are using Swift 2 you need to check for the error using do try and catch. Here's the complete code including checking optionals for nil and handling bad connectivity errors, 404 errors, etc. Also ensures that the URL was valid. Uses the new guard statement to reduce indentation:

```
    guard let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil 
    else 
    {
        // Checks for errors if the task fails like for bad connectivity.
        print(error);
        return;
    }
    do 
    {
        guard let JSONDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [NSObject: AnyObject] 
        else
        {
            // The JSONDict wasn't a dictionary. Maybe its an array here? If it is change the structure of the parsing.
            return
        }
        // Do stuff with the JSONDict which is a Swift dictionary.
        // For example: let some = JSONDict["key"] as? ValueType will allow you to access the key of the JSONDict
    }
    catch error 
    { 
        // JSON parsing error. 
        print(error) 
    }
}
else 
{ 
    // Error task wasn't created that's unusual unless the URL was bad.
    // Fail here so that you can trace the stack and debug.
    assertionFailure();
}
task.resume()
```